# Ionic ion-view class has to be bar-subheader otherwise won't render view

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hey i'm working on this Ionic project and for some reason, my views will only render if the ion-view class equals a class of "bar-subheader". I've been stuck trying to figure out what I did wrong, maybe I've read the docs wrong. What's happening is when the nested state renders, the whole layout of the view is placed with a height equal to the class "bar-subheader" or the view doesn't get rendered at all without a class of "bar-subheader" assigned to the view. In the stores.html, the products are present on the view, but because the ion-view class equals "bar-subheader" you will not see the remaining content. Without a class of "bar-subheader" the content will flash for a half a second and then disappear.

**App.js**

```
    angular.module('ArtSFApp', ['ionic', 'controllers', 'starter.services'])    
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/app.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.store', {
    url: '/store',
    views: {
      'store': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/store.html',
        controller: 'StoreCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.store.artist', {
    url: '/artist',
    views: {
      'artist': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/artist.html',
        controller: 'StoreCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.store.categories', {
      url: '/categories',
      views: {
        'categories': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/categories.html',
          controller: 'StoreCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
  .state('app.store.categories.paintings', {
      url: '/paintings',
      views: {
        'paintings': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/paintings.html',
          controller: 'StoreCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
  .state('app.store.categories.sculptures', {
      url: '/sculptures',
      views: {
        'sculptures': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/sculptures.html',
          controller: 'StoreCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
  .state('app.store.categories.drawings', {
      url: '/drawings',
      views: {
        'drawings': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/drawings.html',
          controller: 'StoreCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
  .state('app.store.categories.prints', {
      url: '/prints',
      views: {
        'prints': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/prints.html',
          controller: 'StoreCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
  .state('app.store.categories.books', {
      url: '/books',
      views: {
        'books': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/books.html',
          controller: 'StoreCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.store.sale', {
      url: '/sale',
      views: {
        'sale': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/sale.html',
          controller: 'StoreCtrl'
        }
      }
    });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/blog');
});
```

**index.html**

```
  <body ng-app="ArtSFApp">
    <ion-header-bar class="main-header bar">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="logo col-offset-10 col-20">
          ArtSFBlog
        </div>
        <label class=" searchbar col-33 col-offset-25 item item-input">
          <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
          <input ui-sref="app.search" type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Search">
        </label>
        <div class="cart">
          <i class="ion-ios-cart" ui-sref="app.cart"></i> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.html**

```
 <ion-tabs class="tabs-top">
  <ion-tab class="navtab" title="Blog" ui-sref="app.blog"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab class="navtab" title="Store" ui-sref="app.store"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab class="navtab" title="Contact" ui-sref="app.contact"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

<ion-view>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-nav-view name="blog"></ion-nav-view>
    <ion-nav-view name="store"></ion-nav-view>
    <ion-nav-view name="contact"></ion-nav-view>
    <ion-nav-view name="search"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**store.html**

```
    <ion-view title="Store" class="bar-subheader">
  <ion-content ng-controller="StoreCtrl" >

    <ion-header  class="bar">
      <ion-panel ng-click="openPopover2($event)" class="tab-item active" ui-sref="app.store.artist">
        Artist 
      </ion-panel>
      <div ng-click="openPopover($event)" ng-click="myFilter = { }" class="tab-item active"  ui-sref="app.store.categories">
        Categories 
      </div>
      <div class="tab-item active" ui-sref="app.store.sale"> 
      Sale
      </div>
    </ion-header>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
<ion-content class='has-subheader'>
  <ion-list ng-repeat="product in products | filter:myFilter">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-panel class="item-thumbnail-left"></ion-panel>
      <h2> {{product.title}} </h2>
      <p> {{product.artist}} </p>
      <p> {{product.description}} </p>
      <p> {{product.dimensions}} </p>
      <p> {{product.price}} </p>
      <p> {{product.quantity}} </p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**controllers.js**

```
  angular.module('controllers', [])
.controller('StoreCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopover) {
  $scope.products = [
  {
    type: "painting",
    title: "painting1",
    artist: "artist",
    description: "description",
    dimensions: "10 x 10",
    price: "$0.00"
  },
   {
    type: "painting",
    title: "painting2",
    artist: "artist",
    description: "description",
    dimensions: "10 x 10",
    price: "$0.00"
  },
   {
    type: "drawing",
    title: "drawing1",
    artist: "artist",
    description: "description",
    dimensions: "10 x 10",
    price: "$0.00"
  },
  {
    type: "zines",
    title: "zine",
    artist: "artist",
    description: "description",
    dimensions: "10 x 10",
    price: "$0.00"
  }
  ];
    $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('templates/categories.html', {
      scope: $scope,
    }).then(function(popover) {
      $scope.popover = popover;
      console.log('opening');
    });


     $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('templates/artist.html', {
      scope: $scope,
    }).then(function(popover2) {
      $scope.popover2 = popover2;
      console.log('opening');
    });
      $scope.openPopover2 = function($event) {
        $scope.popover2.show($event);
        console.log('opened');

     };
      $scope.openPopover = function($event) {
        $scope.popover.show($event);
        console.log('opened');
     };

});
```

**categories.html**

```
    <ion-popover-view> 
  <ion-content>
    <div class="list">
        <a class="item" ng-click="myFilter ={paintings}" ui-sref="app.store.categories.paintings">Painting</a>
        <a class="item" ng-click="myFilter ={type: sculpture}" ui-sref="app.store.categories.sculpture">Sculpture</a>
        <a class="item" ng-click="myFilter ={type: drawings}" ui-sref="app.store.categories.drawings">Drawings</a>
        <a class="item" ng-click="myFilter ={type: prints}" ui-sref="app.store.categories.prints">Prints</a>
        <a class="item" ng-click="myFilter ={type: books}" ui-sref="app.store.categories.books">Books</a>
        <a class="item" ng-click="myFilter ={zines}" ui-sref="app.store.categories.zines">Zines</a>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-popover-view>
```

Comment: too much code..try to reduce it. so that it would be easy to understand the problem statement.

Comment: I reduced it to one view and one the controller for that view and it's nested view.

Comment: codepen or plunker would be very useful.